# Navigating code using Ctrl-F, and CodeRush Markers

Tags: devexpress, coderush

When I use the 'Jump To ...' context menu CodeRush drops a marker before jumping, so that I can navigate back.

When I CTRL-F in Visual Studio it doesn't.

How can I configure CodeRush to add this handy little navigation aide.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok simple enough

- Create a new Shortcut using [instructions found here](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/rorybecker/archive/2010/10/05/binding-keys-in-coderush.aspx)
- Specify **Ctrl+F** as the Key
- Specify **MarkerDrop** as the Command
- Then check the "after executing this command, pass shortcut to IDE for default handling" checkbox.

**Ctrl+F** should now drop a marker whenever it launches the Find Dialog.

More detail and bonus Marker tips are [available here](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/rorybecker/archive/2011/04/12/coderush-tip-enhance-studio-s-find-command.aspx)